# PHP script dies after each error

Tags: php

Im trying to make my script output the error on screen but the error keeps outputting into error_log and killing the script,

This is my current code

```
        try{
            $db->query("SELECT `test`.`test` FROM `test` WHERE `test`.`test` = test");
            echo("no work?");
        }catch(PDOException $er){
            print("Still dont work");
        }
```

`$db->query...` returns a error like it should but the script dies there, outputs into the error_log and wont finish it like i would like it to.

Can anyone help?

Just to sum up some of the responses i got, it is not the actual die() function that is killing the script, it's the error it's self at `$db->query()`.

Comment: `ini_set('display_errors','On');` anyone? Or the problem is actually in that OP considered `die()` to be a native PHP output function?

Comment: @raina77ow I removed die(); from the script, its still kill's it at `$db->query()`

Comment: Never share the output into error_log with anyone, because it might actually HELP.

Comment: @Sven Im not sure what your saying here, i still want it to output into the error_log but i want the script to stop killing its self every time it outputs something in there.

Comment: Make sure you have PDO set to throw exceptions... check out PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE at this link: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php

Comment: @JasonFingar Thanks for the response but after i set the PDO errormode the script still kills it's self at `$db->query()` not allowing it to continue with the output of an error message.

Comment: Hmm... I copied your code onto a script with a PDO object ready, and it did output the "Still don't Work" line... I'm guessing you have some kind of fatal error somewhere further up in your script... are you sure you have display_errors turned on and working correctly?

Comment: @JasonFingar In my init script i have `error_reporting(-1);` and ill have to check in my php.ini

Comment: @JasonFingar I changed my php.ini to show errors, but what i'm looking for it for the script to not kill after the error occurs so i can pass a error to the user or to redirect the user.

Answer (score 3):

As the name would suggest, `die()` makes your script die (i.e, exit) after printing the message you pass it.

If you just want it to print the error, use `print()` instead of `die()`.

Comment: I understand that die(); kills the script but it will not echo `no work?` it just dies at $->db not needing the die(); command.

Comment: Have you tried it since changing the command from die to print?

Comment: @BenGriffiths Yes, its still the same thing.

Comment: When an exception is thrown (e.g, by PDO), execution of code passes immediately to the `catch` block; none of the following code in the `try` block is executed. There is no `ON ERROR RESUME NEXT` in PHP, nor in any sane language for that matter.

Comment: @duskwuff i understnad this but the script kills at the error, it dont pass to the catch block nor do anything else.